# void в параметре конструктора C++

Tags: c++

При изучении ООП возник вопрос по поводу конструкторов.

```
class A 
{
    public:
    A(void);// конструктор по умолчанию
    ~A(void);//деструктор 
};
```

Почему в параметрах конструктора и деструктора мы пишем `void` ?

Answer (score 6):

Тема не имеет никакого отношения именно к конструкторам или деструкторам. Список параметров вида `(void)` означает, что у функции нет параметров. Это применимо к любым функциям. В С++ то же самое можно записать просто как `()`.

Так что никакой необходимости писать `(void)` нет. Я бы сказал, что такая манера записывать функции без параметров является в C++ весьма редкой (в отличие от C). В подавляющем большинстве случаев в C++ коде пишут именно `()`, а не `(void)`.

Писать `(void)` в функциях без параметров может иметь смысл в кросс-компилируемых заголовочных файлах, компилируемых и как C++, и как C код. Но к случаю объявления методов классов эти соображения, разумеется, не применимы.

Comment: Просто раньше в си наличие void говорило, что параметров точно нет. А вот пустые скобки обозначали, что количество параметров неизвестно. В плюсах это сознательно исправили, но синтаксис с void оставили для обратной совместимости. Но старички и те, кто читает очень древнюю литературу, продолжают так писать.